# How do I use different Post-Processing effects on different cameras in Unity 2017.4.2f2?

Tags: unity-game-engine, post-processing

***Before I explain my situation, it's important that I mention I'm using an older version of Unity, 2017.42f2 (for PSVITA support). for this reason, I'm also using the old Post-Processing Stack.***

---

I'm making a game in which I want a lot of bloom on the UI, but not as much for the rest of the game. I used a camera to render the UI, gave it Post-Processing (`Screen Space - Camera` on Canvas),

[image]

and another one to render the rest of the game

[image]

Each is given a different profile to use different effects.

---

My expectation is that the UI renderer camera would only apply it's effects to the Canvas. Instead, it also applies them to the camera beneath it; the game renderer camera.

As you can see I used `Don't Clear` clear flags. I also tried `Depth-only`, to see if it would make a difference.

I'm lost as to what I could do. Grain and bloom get applied to everything

[image]

yet the profile for those effects is only given to the UI renderer Camera's Post Processing Behavior Script.

[image: Everything shown]

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas? I'm lost.